# Returning and printing without assigning to variable?

Tags: python

Just curious if there is a way to both print and return within one function without assigning the output to variable?

Consider this code:

```
def secret_number(secret_number_range):
    return random.randrange(1, secret_number_range + 1)
```

Is there a way to reference that variable stored for the purpose of return statement?

Comment: Maybe by making another function like :
     def print_and_return(value):
           print value
           return value
But anyway, your random.randrange will assign either something into his function, so I don't understand why don't you want to store the output?

Comment: @Raito please, do not attempt to understand for your own sake :). I was just curious whether it was possible.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I think there is no any direct or "easy" way of doing this. However, one way would be to define a decorator that prints this. For example:

```
    import random        

    def print_return(func):
        def func_wrapper(param):
            rv =   func(param)
            print("Return value: {0}".format(rv))
            return rv
        return func_wrapper

    @print_return
    def secret_number(secret_number_range):
        return random.randrange(1, secret_number_range + 1)

    # with this, this call would result in "Return value: 3" being printed.
    c=secret_number(4)
```